# How to tell when Canvas animation ends

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas

I am trying to be able to tell when each part of a Canvas animation comes to an end, so that I can reload it.

Each 'pod' should reach the end of its first journey, and then go to a random one of the next available stations, and then do it again in an endless loop (or a very long one).

Right now the code for finding the next station works, but I cannot get the trigger for the end of the animation of each individual pod. I know that when

```
 aPod.currentPoint + 1 == aPod.points.length - 1
```

the pod has reached its destination station, but nothing then happens.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/f9nob149/1/

I have been banging my head against this for a week, and really need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you just have to check when your `currentPoint` is the last point of the pod's `points`.

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1j9rwfc/) where I created the `doneCallback`. I also had to add the `done` pod property so that it is not called several times.

By the way, this is horrible and does not do what I think you think it does:

```
new Pod(
  startX = fromX,
  startY = fromY,
  endX = toX,
  endY = toY,
  riders = randomPass(),
  color = colorArray[riders - 1],
  points = linePoints({
    startX, startY
  }, {
     endX, endY
  }),
  currentPoint = 0)
```

**JavaScript does not support named arguments** like python for example does. What this is doing, is assigning all the values at the right of the `=` to new variables created on the global scope (because they are declared without `var`), then forward these values to your `Pod` constructor **in order** (and not by what you may think is names). Also some browsers will refuse it (i.e. Safari), and it is not allowed in `strict` mode (nor with next javascript version (ES6) I think).

What you can do however is use an objet as argument:

```
function Pod(args){
  this.startX = args.startX;
  this.startY = args.startY;
  // Etc.
}

var pod = new Pod({
  startY: fromY,
  startX: fromX // Order does not matter anymore.
  // Etc.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not sure where I picked up that form of creating constructors -- trying to teach myself online with fragments of other people's works probably leads to bad habits. I did notice the order issue, but as the form generally seemed to work I didn't think too much about it.